# Looping over elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to loop over the elements of an HTML form, and store the values of the <input> fields in an object. The following code doesn't work, though:

```
function config() {
    $("#frmMain").children().map(function() {
        var child = $("this");
        if (child.is(":checkbox"))
            this[child.attr("name")] = child.attr("checked");
        if (child.is(":radio, checked"))
            this[child.attr("name")] = child.val();
        if (child.is(":text"))
            this[child.attr("name")] = child.val();
        return null;
    });
```

Neither does the following (inspired by jobscry's answer):

```
function config() {
    $("#frmMain").children().each(function() {
        var child = $("this");
        alert(child.length);
        if (child.is(":checkbox")) {
            this[child.attr("name")] = child.attr("checked");
        }
        if (child.is(":radio, checked"))
            this[child.attr("name")] = child.val();
        if (child.is(":text"))
            this[child.attr("name")] = child.val();
    });
}
```

The alert always shows that `child.length == 0`. Manually selecting the elements works:

```
    
>>> $("#frmMain").children()
Object length=42
>>> $("#frmMain").children().filter(":checkbox")
Object length=3
```

Any hints on how to do the loop correctly?

Comment: Your thread just saved me 20 minutes of line by line input fields for multiple forms -_-;. +1.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

don't think you need quotations on this:

```
var child = $("this");
```

try:

```
var child = $(this);
```

Answer (score 28):

jQuery has an excellent function for looping through a set of elements:  [.each()](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each)

```
$('#formId').children().each(
    function(){
        //access to form element via $(this)
    }
);
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, see my edit of the question. Further ideas?

Comment: The form will likely have a paragraph or something similar as its child. You need to make sure you only select input elements.

Comment: "children()" gets all of the DOM children within the form, not the elements.

Answer (score 13):

Depending on what you need each child for (if you're looking to post it somewhere via AJAX) you can just do...

```
$("#formID").serialize()
```

It creates a string for you with all of the values automatically.

As for looping through objects, you can also do this.

```
$.each($("input, select, textarea"), function(i,v) {
    var theTag = v.tagName;
    var theElement = $(v);
    var theValue = theElement.val();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I have used the following before:

```
var my_form = $('#form-id');
var data = {};

$('input:not([type=checkbox]), input[type=checkbox]:selected, select, textarea', my_form).each(
    function() {
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        var val = $(this).val();

        if (!data.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            data[name] = new Array;
        }

        data[name].push(val);
    }
);
```

This is just written from memory, so might contain mistakes, but this should make an object called `data` that contains the values for all your inputs.

Note that you have to deal with checkboxes in a special way, to avoid getting the values of unchecked checkboxes. The same is probably true of radio inputs.

Also note using arrays for storing the values, as for one input name, you might have values from several inputs (checkboxes in particular).

Comment: Did you vote me down for that? $(this) isn't a lookup, you're wrapping an existing object with a jQuery object. It might be slightly more efficient to only do this once, but the difference will be marginal.

Comment: Out of all of the many suggestions I've seen, this is the easiest to implement.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the each function, it should look like this:

```
$('#formId').children().each( 
  function(){
    //access to form element via $(this)
  }
);
```

Just switch out the closing curly bracket for a close paren.  Thanks for pointing it out, jobscry, you saved me some time.

Comment: Why did you post this as an answer when you say you're just replying to `jobscry`? It's the same code he posted. That is what comments are for.

Answer (score 0):

for me all these didn't work. What worked for me was something really simple:

```
$("#formID input[type=text]").each(function() {
alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the simplest way to loop through a form accessing only the form elements. Inside the each function you can check and build whatever you want.  When building objects note that you will want to declare it outside of the each function.

EDIT
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UDD7E/6/)

The below will work

```
$('form[name=formName]').find('input, textarea, select').each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

Comment: `$('#formId input, select, textarea')` will return all `input` elements in the form, along with *every select box and textarea in the page*.

Comment: It actually doent behave like that... Using that exact format in JSFiddle actually resulted in only the select and textarea echoing. Adding a comma in front of 'input' results it what you are saying.

Comment: Really?  Cause http://jsfiddle.net/UDD7E/3/ shows exactly what i was talking about.  Both select boxes and both textareas are red, even though one of each is outside the form.

Comment: Interesting, I got different results.  Maybe it is because I launched it on a button click.  Very strange.  I'd throw up a fiddle but doesnt matter anymore.

Comment: Just noticed the edit.  The new code should work better, as you're grabbing the form and querying it (which restricts the query in a way the other code didn't).  The code above it is still broken, and you might want to get rid of it, but at least you have something that works now.  :)

Comment: How is it still broken? J/w

Comment: It's still broken because the commas separate selectors.  `form[name=formname] input, select, textarea` means "all `input`s in the form named `formname`, plus all `select`s, plus all `textarea`s".  You might be able to say `$('input, select, textarea', 'form[name=formname]')` and have it work; i forget whether jQuery lets you do that or makes you use an element or jQuery object as context.

Comment: Oh you're still look at the top old stuff... Its the edit at the bottom that works and is in the JSFiddle

Comment: Yeah..that's what i was saying.  The bottom stuff works.  The code above it should probably be taken out, as it's incorrect.